# Reasons to create an external RESTful API for an existing Grpc design

Tags: rest, grpc, api-design, system-design

Currently my org has a pretty tightly coupled Grpc API design for their internal microservices use. However looking through all the requirements as it stands and the amount of interest other orgs (big company) are showing in our service, I feel like we could benefit from just mapping it to a whole new RESTful style API Service for external vendors and orgs to use, instead of just stretching out the current design to cater to both internal and external teams.

One of the big cons of this decision is of course the upfront overhead work required, however I think it's an overall net benefit.

Is there something I'm missing about this idea that no writeups about this exist?

I'd love to explore further tradeoffs about this idea before moving it up the ladder.

Comment: Very general and unclear.

Comment: Anything I could elaborate on specifically?

Comment: Q1 : Why RESTful style APIs ? 

Q2 : Will it be an exact mapping ?

Comment: Q1: It's a much easier resource oriented style that caters to much broader needs, as opposed to very specified payloads that need to be created for each orgs specific use case. Q2: No